# Cypress graphql apollo call gives no result and retries automatically

Tags: graphql, cypress, apollo, fixtures, quasar

The problem is that instead of mocked I got a loading screen with unresolved query, Cypress make several attempts to re-query it again, and there is no error messages.

I'm using Cypress from Quasar-testing harness. I'd like to mock `graphql` call.

In my component I have an `apollo` query:

```js
apollo: {
  assetsOverview: {
    query: ASSETS_OVERVIEW,
    loadingKey: 'loading'
  }
}
```

For that purpose I'm using fixtures in such way:

```js
cy.intercept('POST', api, req => {
  if (req.body.operationName === 'getAssetOverview') {
    // This condition works just fine
    req.reply({
      fixture: 'asset-table.json'
    })
  }
})
```

My fixture looks like this:

```js
{ 
  "assetsOverview": {
    "assetMetrics": [
      {
        "assetId": "todo-conveyor",
        "assetName": "Conveyor belts",
        "childAssetIds": null,
        "oeeMetrics": {
          "availability": null,
          "oee": null,
          "performance": null,
          "quality": null,
          "__typename": "AssetOeeMetrics"
        },
        "stateMetrics": {
          "blocked": null,
          "failed": null,
          "idle": null,
          "running": null,
          "stopped": null,
          "__typename": "AssetStateMetrics"
        },
        "__typename": "AssetMetrics"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "AssetMetricsOverview"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that I have to wrap my fixtures object within `data`.

Like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "assetsOverview": {
      "assetMetrics": [
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```